# Apply CSS to Custom Visualforce Chart

Tags: visualforce-charting

[image: Custom VF Chart]

We have developed a Custom VF Chart as shown above. Now our requirement is to beautify the chart(bars and texts) and its legends by applying the css on it. Can we apply css on the chart tag and legends? Is there any way to do so because css was not applicable on it? Please let me know if anyone has come across similar kind of requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question appears to be "No". See [Controlling the Appearance of Charts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_appearance.htm) in the Visualforce Developer's Guide. Other than the fact some tags are children of other tags, charting css attributes are set up to be called out as tags in the Visualforce/Apex code markup that creates them. That means they're largely controlled by standard stylesheets along with the attributes that you specify.